# Install4j restore version

Tags: install4j

I've added a custom application to my installer project and use it as recovery tool if something went wrong during update or if the new application data contains any bugs.

So far so good, restoring files and database works, but I can't figure out how to restore the version number. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to restore the file `.install4j/i4jparams.conf` in the installation directory. It contains the version number, also the file `.install4j/response.varfile` if you query installer variables in your code.